# Extracción de información de líneas de diferentes longitudes en JAVA

Tags: java, lista, arraylist

Me encuentro ante el problema de que tengo un archivo con varias líneas. Tras extraerlo en un `List<String>` y eliminar algunas partes me queda algo como lo siguiente:

```
1x5, 100x100
(1,1): 1 {R100G100B255, REC:{R0G250B255, R, 50,100}}
(1,2): 1 {R0G0B255, REC:{R0G250B255, R, 50,100}}
(1,3): 1 {R0G0B255}
(1,5): 1 {R0G0B255, CIR:{R0G250B255, C,35}
```

De cada línea quiero extraer la posición (x,y), el flag que me indique si existe o no (sería el siguiente 1), el color primario (R100G100B255) y si tiene un dibujo (Rec o Cir) y las características de ese dibujo. (Si alguna posición falta se rellena con unos valores por defecto).

Probé a hacerlo de una manera 'manual' con `data.get(i).chartAt(x)` pero al ser líneas de diferente longitud lógicamente no me sirve.

Alguna idea de cómo debo afrontarlo? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Con expresiones regulares

Comment: Ya que tienes la seguridad de que en tu x no existe el símbolo `,` y que los diez primeros caracteres `(1,2): 1 {` no forman parte de y, debería funcionar algo como lo siguiente: `input.substring(10, input.indexOf(','))`, ya teniendo la longitud de x te será más fácil obtener y. Pero solo funcionaría si x,y<=9. Caso contrario deberás identificar también la posición del primer { con `input.indexOf`

Comment: Como sugirió Alfabravo, te recomiendo investigar sobre expresiones regulares y hacer algunas pruebas en páginas como debuggex.com y regex101.com, es algo que te va a facilitar muchísimo la tarea de búsqueda de cosas particulares como estas en textos